# Panel's Anchor Property not working as desired

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, panel

I have a delphi form of dimensions say (600 * 400) i.e, width = 600 and height = 400. I have kept 3 panels on it of same size with dimensions (150 * 300) which are equidistant from each other.

Now, I need that when I resize the form (make smaller or bigger manually or by maximize button), panels should resize themselves with the form.

I am using anchors property for this. But its not working as desired. Panels are getting overlapped with each other. I am confused which anchor property to set true or which to false to accomplish this functionality. Please help me out in this.

Comment: did you read the [anchors documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel.Anchors)?

Anchors may not work as you desire, but will work as documented!

Comment: Yes, I did read. I have Anchors property set to [akTop, akBottom, akLeft] for panels. This stretches my each panel to bottom and top by maintaining left relative position. But how should I make them to stretch to the right also or should I code for this?

Comment: You need akRight as well to make them stretch, but I don't think it is going to solve the overlapping because what anchors do is fix the absolute distance to the side of the form. So if the left hand panel's right is 450 away from the right, it is gonna stay that way, regardless of the fact that the right hand panel's left is gonna stay 450 from the left...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to position and resize them manually. You can use the panel's owner's OnReSize-Method.

```
procedure TOwnerForm.OnResize(Sender : TObject);
begin
  panel1.width := Self.Width div 3;
  panel2.width := Self.width - 2*panel1.Width;
  panel3.width := Self.Width - panel1.Width - panel2.Width;
  panel1.Left := 0;
  panel2.Left := panel1.left + panel1.width;
  panel3.left := panel2.left + panel2.width;
  panel1.top := 0;
  panel2.top := panel1.top;
  panel3.top := panel1.top;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was thinking that I will have to code for it. Accepted your answer.

Comment: In VCL I prefer working with TGridPanel rather that setting size and position on form resize event.

Comment: Hi I don't have the TGridPanel, that's why I would still use the above handcoding. It's not a big deal either, but in a modern Delphi, I would recommend your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ive tended to attack this another way (for right or wrong), where you have a panel "aligned" to one side of a form or another using the "Align" property.  I often then choose a master panel aligned to "client" to take up the majority of the space available when resized (so, one panel aligned to left, another to top, and a 3rd to client.  You can have panels within panels, and use the splitter component with this to allow the user to resize as required.  This may not be the result you are after, but certainly avoids the overlap problem, just a matter of what needs to be where i guess.

Perhaps you want things to scale however, so every panel maintains the same aspect ratio?  Given you tagged XE2, if this is a FireMonkey form, then i think scaling the form would be an option (see here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42560)